# Reference a set variable while extracting from JSON

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to dynamically load parts of a JSON object using a set variable, the reason for this is so that when a user navigates to 'page 3', I can request the third child of a JSON snippet to load the relevant data.

I want to be able to dynamically pick that I'd like "2", like so:

```
  var steps = (data)

  const x = '2'
  console.log(steps[x])
```

When doing so in a react-native iOS environment, I get:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'steps[x]')

---

**My JSON (data):**

```
{
   "0":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Check Equipment",
      "scope":"equipment",
      "type":"instruction"
   },
   "1":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Check Out Equipment",
      "scope":"equipment",
      "type":"scan"
   },
   "2":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Start Job",
      "scope":"job",
      "type":"instruction",
   },
   "3":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Confirm Job",
      "scope":"job",
      "type":"instruction"
   }
}
```

Comment: data seems undefined. how do you fill it ?

Comment: data is the json, it is defined as it's pulled from DynamoDB, if I log 'data' it returns the json I posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is a json string you have to use JSON.parse(data) to get a js object

```js
var data = `{
   "0":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Check Equipment",
      "scope":"equipment",
      "type":"instruction"
   },
   "1":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Check Out Equipment",
      "scope":"equipment",
      "type":"scan"
   },
   "2":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Start Job",
      "scope":"job",
      "type":"instruction"
   },
   "3":{
      "action":"########",
      "detail":"########",
      "items":"########",
      "meta":"########",
      "name":"Confirm Job",
      "scope":"job",
      "type":"instruction"
   }
}`;


var steps = JSON.parse(data);

const x = '2';
console.log(steps[x]);
```

I data is a js object you can directly use it

```js
var data = {
  "0": {
    "action": "########",
    "detail": "########",
    "items": "########",
    "meta": "########",
    "name": "Check Equipment",
    "scope": "equipment",
    "type": "instruction"
  },
  "1": {
    "action": "########",
    "detail": "########",
    "items": "########",
    "meta": "########",
    "name": "Check Out Equipment",
    "scope": "equipment",
    "type": "scan"
  },
  "2": {
    "action": "########",
    "detail": "########",
    "items": "########",
    "meta": "########",
    "name": "Start Job",
    "scope": "job",
    "type": "instruction"
  },
  "3": {
    "action": "########",
    "detail": "########",
    "items": "########",
    "meta": "########",
    "name": "Confirm Job",
    "scope": "job",
    "type": "instruction"
  }
};


var steps = data;

const x = '2';
console.log(steps[x]);
```